# Hide/disable sidebar using shortcode?

Tags: theme-development, sidebar, shortcode

The question is pretty simple, but it's complex in fact.

I have implemented custom sidebars for each post/page function in my blog.

It looks like:

```
<div id="<?php echo get_option('sidebar-layout');" ?>
 <div id="content">
   Some content
   [myshortcode]
 </div>
 <div id="sidebar">
   Sidebar 
 </div>
</div>
```

sidebar-layout option can have three values - left, right and none. And none is default. They are all set via metabox under post/page.

The biggest problem here is that when user chooses left - the first div gets "left" class and everything else is based on this ID, eg.

```
#left #content {
     style;
}
```

And when he takes "right" then different style is applied:

```
#right #content {
     another style;
}
```

So my "myshortcode" should basically change parents DIV id.

Any ideas how to achieve that? I believe my shortcode will be executed AFTER the div ID.

Comment: Can you explain the link between your shortcode and your `sidebar-layout` setting? The way you describe it, it looks like you use post metadata. Your code example uses `get_option()` which reads site-wide options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to echo your div's ID

```
<?php $sidebar_layout = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sidebar-layout', $single = true); ?>
<div id="<?php echo $sidebar_layout ?>">
    <div class="content">
         ...
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want to apply styles according to the selection the user has made then change your style sheet as follows:

```
#left .content{ ... }
#left .sidebar{ ... }
#right .content{ ... }
#right .sidebar{ ... }
#none .content{ ... }
#none .sidebar{ ... }
```

I hope this helps.